#  LongListSelector with TextBlock and Checkbox - How to change checked status of Checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I have a list of type LongListSelector in my Windows Phone app. The list has a TextBlock and a Checkbox for each item.

I have a binding that marks the Checkbox as `isChecked` when the list is populated, but how can I change the `checked` status of the Checkbox when a user changes the selection?

My XAML looks like this:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector Name="DictList" Visibility="Visible" Margin="10,98,10,40" SelectionChanged="DictList_SelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="28" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" Background="White" Padding="10" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32"  />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="White" Background="White" Padding="10" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

I have implemented this code when selection changes:

```
private void DictList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    helpers.parrot.DictionaryItem dictItem = this.DictList.SelectedItem as helpers.parrot.DictionaryItem;

    if (dictItem != null)
    {
        dictItem.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

How to do this in code? Any suggestions?

**Updated to match comments:**

DictionaryItem looks like this, where i have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface

```
namespace Dict.helpers.parrot
{
    public class DictionaryItem : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string DictId { get; private set; }
        public string MethodId { get; private set; }
        private bool checkedValue = true;
        public bool Checked {
            get
            {
                return checkedValue;
            }
            set
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Checked");
                this.checkedValue = value;
            }
        }

        public DictionaryItem(string name, string dictId, string methodId)
        {
            Name = name;
            DictId = dictId;
            MethodId = methodId;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

My DictionaryCategory looks like this. This object holds each DictionaryItem.

```
namespace Dict.helpers.parrot
{
    public class DictionaryCategory:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DictionaryItem>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public DictionaryCategory(string categoryName)
        {
            Name = categoryName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in DictionaryItem class?

Comment: Yes i did implement this. I have updated my question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - now i got it working.

My Selection Changed event now looks like this

```
private void DictList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    helpers.parrot.DictionaryItem dictItem = this.DictList.SelectedItem as helpers.parrot.DictionaryItem;

    if (dictItem != null)
    {
        dictItem.Checked = !dictItem.Checked;
    }

    LongListSelector _sender = (LongListSelector)sender;
    _sender.SelectedItem = -1;
}
```

in DictionaryItem I changed the following

```
  public bool Checked {
        get
        {
            return checkedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Checked");
            this.checkedValue = value;
        }
    }
```

to

```
  public bool Checked {
        get
        {
            return checkedValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.checkedValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Checked");
        }
    }
```